# Use of uninitialized value of size 4

Tags: c++

## Edit: I was being dumb, I -WASN'T- allocating it. Thanks again for the help!

This is an error I had thought myself to be over, yet it's back at it, and I do not know why it's happening.

Here is the code from the .C file leading up to the error:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( argc > 3 )
    {
        cout << "Too many arguments. Program will close.\n";
        return 1;
    }
     
    else
    {
        int numRooms = 0;
        int start = 0;
        ifstream file;
    
        if( argc == 3 )//Dump wanted
            file.open( argv[ 2 ] , ifstream::in );
        
        else 
            file.open( argv[ 1 ] , ifstream::in );
    

        if( file.is_open() )
        {
            file >> numRooms;
            Graph * maze = new Graph( numRooms );
```

The **Graph * maze = new Graph( numRooms );** is where the error is being referenced (a11.C:41):

```
==17900== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==17900==    at 0x8048F05: Graph::Graph(int) (Graph.C:25)
==17900==    by 0x8048C1D: main (a11.C:41)
```

From here we delve deeper, into the Graph.C file, lines 16 - 30:

```
Graph::Graph( int num )
{
    numRooms = num;
    _index = 0;
    _start = 0;

    easyDelete = new Room*[ num ];
    escapePath = new string[ num ];

    theWALL -> myNumber = -1;
    theWALL -> visited = true;

    safety -> myNumber = 0;
    safety -> visited = false;
}
```

Line 25 is this: **theWALL -> myNumber = -1;**

"theWALL" and "safety" are both private *Room objects:

```
Private:
    Room * theWALL;
    Room * safety;
```

The struct "Room" looks like this:

```
struct Room
    {
        bool visited;
        int myNumber;

        Room *North;
        Room *East;
        Room *South;
        Room *West;
    };
```

---

It's initialized up when I call new Graph( numRooms ), and I am filling it it's information... yet I get this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are not allocating

```
Room * theWALL;
```

before using it at

```
theWALL -> myNumber = -1;
```

try something like

```
theWall = new Room();
theWALL -> myNumber = -1;
```

And you have the same bug for:

```
 Room * safety;
```

try allocating that too.